# Erro "There is already an object named '#TEMP' in the database"

Tags: sql-server

Estou realizando uma carga, utilizando uma tabela temporária no *Microsoft SQL Server 2008*.

```
SELECT CAMPO1,
        CAMPO2,
        CAMPO3,
        CAMPO4 
     INTO #TEMP 
     FROM DADOS
```

Na consulta, utilizo o seguinte comando, para verificar se a tabela temporária existe, se a tabela existe realizo o **DROP TABLE**, conforme o exemplo abaixo.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TEMP') IS NOT NULL   
BEGIN       
    DROP TABLE #TEMP    
END
```

Após a execução realizada a tabela continua criada no banco **tempdb**

Se executo somente:

```
DROP TABLE #TEMP
```

É retomado a mensagem:

> Msg 3701, Level 11, State 5, Line 1
>
> Cannot drop the table '#TEMP', because it does not exist or you do not
>   have permission.

Só é possível realizar nova carga somente após desconectar do servidor.

Peço a ajuda.

Comment: Questão idiota, mas que precisa de ser respondida. O *login* que esta a usar tem permissões para usar o `DROP`?

Comment: Tente usar ##TEMP, com 2 #

Comment: A tabela #TEMP quando se utiliza apenas um # é temporária da seção, verifique se todos comando executados referente a sua #TEMP estão na mesma seção do SQL Server.

Comment: Sempre utilize ## nas tabelas temporárias se você precisar as apagar de outra sessão. Acredito que possa ser isto. E também após o segundo ponto você precisa passar o banco, por exemplo 'tempdb.dbo.#TEMP'. Espero que te ajude, forte abraço! Att.,
Wilson Gomes

Answer (score 0):

Tente o codigo abaixo

```
IF EXITS( SELECT TOP 1 * FROM tempdb..#TEMP)

BEGIN

DROP TABLE #TEMP

END
```

Answer (score -2):

Tente assim amigo, ele buscando direto no sys object.

```
IF EXISTS (Select * FROM tempdb..sysobjects WHERE id=OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TEMP')) DROP TABLE #TEMP
```